# Cursor inside IF() Then

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

It is Possible to use Cursor inside IF() Then Condition? I tried the below code
But it's working.. anyone help me to resolve this?

My Code is:

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS 
((select '1'
  from cttest c
 where not exists( 
 select 1  from cof o where  c.createddate > add_months(sysdate,-6) and c.ctid not in (
 o.ctid , o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1,o.sslc2) 
 ) and c.lastupdated is null and c.lastupdatedcof is null)) THEN
begin
cursor ctdelete 
IS
 select ctid,ctname  from cttest c
 where not exists( 
 select 1  from cof o where  c.createddate > add_months(sysdate,-6) and c.ctid not in (
 o.ctid , o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1,o.sslc2) 
 ) and c.lastupdated is null and c.lastupdatedcof is null
end;
FOR reDel_audit IN ctdelete
  LOOP 
 insert into ctaudit (ctid,ctname,v_IsDeleted,null,sysdate); 
COMMIT; 
END LOOP;
END;
```

Error  is:

Error(22,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ctdelete" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;

Comment: Do you even need the first cursor? Your FOR LOOP will evaluate the presence of a record.

Comment: @Drumbeg Based upon the cursor result i need iterate the each row and insert into ctaudit table..

Comment: Well, the cursors look the same to me pretty much. Don't think you need to check for existence of a record before doing a loop based on the same criteria.

Comment: In PL/SQL context you cannot just use `SELECT` statement without fetching it's result into some variable (besides the implicit cursors used in `FOR` loops).
Also, as @Drumbeg stated, if your cursor does not return any data, statements inside your `FOR` loop won't be executed (because it has no data to iterate over).

Comment: Oh. And you get the exception, because you declare your `ctdelete` cursor inside the execution block. You cannot declare cursors within `BEGIN` - `END` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not evaluate the existence of a record in that way.

One way could be using a variable to store the result of a query, and then evaluate the variable in an `IF`; for example:

```
create table test(a) as (
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual
)    

declare
    vCount  number;
begin
    select count(1)
    into vCount
    from test; 
    --
    if vCount > 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line(vCount || ' rows found');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('No rows found');
    end if;
    --
    for i in ( 
                select a
                from test
             )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Value: ' || i.a);
    end loop; 
end;
```

If you only need to insert data from a table to another, you don't need any check, `IF`, `loop`... you can simply do:

```
insert into table2(a, b, c)
select a, b, c
from table1
where ...
```

Comment: i need to know how to use cursor inside the for loop

Comment: You don't need a cursor, you can use a loop in a simpler way. Just edited to show an example

Answer (score 0):

How about writing it like this? Just iterate over your cursor and mark each found row as deleted.

```
BEGIN
   CURSOR ctdelete IS
      SELECT ctid, ctname
        FROM cttest c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT 1
                FROM cof o
               WHERE c.createddate > add_months(SYSDATE, -6)
                 AND c.ctid NOT IN
                     (o.ctid, o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1, o.sslc2))
         AND c.lastupdated IS NULL
         AND c.lastupdatedcof IS NULL;

   FOR redel_audit IN ctdelete
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO ctaudit
         (redel_audit.ctid, redel_audit.ctname, 'Y', NULL, SYSDATE);
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cursor i did like this: it's working fine.. Thanks all for your valuable replies.. i tried lot.. thanks

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Contact Delete');
    SELECT COUNT(ctid)
    INTO v_count
    FROM cttest c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
      FROM cof o
      WHERE c.createddate > add_months(sysdate,-6)
      AND c.ctid NOT                          IN ( o.ctid , o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1,o.sslc2)
      )
    AND c.lastupdated    IS NULL
    AND c.lastupdatedcof IS NULL;
    IF v_count            >0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count==>'||v_count);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleted Status==>'||v_IsDeleted);
      INSERT
      INTO ctaudit
        (
          ctid,
          ctname,
          isdeleted,
          ismasked,
          updatedon
        )
        (SELECT ctid,
            ctname,
            'Y'     AS isdeleted,
            NULL    AS ismasked,
            SYSDATE AS updatedon
          FROM cttest c
          WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1
            FROM cof o
            WHERE c.createddate > add_months(sysdate,-6)
            AND c.ctid NOT                          IN ( o.ctid , o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1,o.sslc2)
            )
          AND C.Lastupdated    IS NULL
          AND C.Lastupdatedcof IS NULL
        );
    END IF;
    DELETE
    FROM cttest c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
      FROM cof o
      WHERE c.createddate   > add_months(sysdate,-6)
      AND c.ctid NOT                            IN ( o.ctid , o.bctid, o.lc1, o.lc2, o.sslc1,o.sslc2)
      AND c.lastupdated    IS NULL
      AND c.lastupdatedcof IS NULL
      );
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Compelted.......');
  END;
```